# Updating an observable on key press and click event

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a value binding that looks like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Comments" rows="10" data-bind="value: $root.GetTabComment($data).Comment, valueUpdate: 'keyup'"></textarea>
```

The reason I use `keyup`, is because I have a "save as you type" system set up. This works great as the user is typing, but if they correct spelling through spell check (using mouse clicks and no keyboard at all), the binding will not update.

The bound variable Comment is declared as:

`Comment = ko.observable("").extend({throttle: 1000})`

And the subscription is simply:

```
Comment.subscribe(function(){
  //save code
});
```

Is there some way for me to force the binding to take on the current value of the text area when a button is clicked?

Comment: how often does it save? and are you using an observable?

Comment: Yes, it is an observable. It saves whenever the binding updates, I used `.extend {throttle: 1000}` so that it doesn't do so on every keystroke.

Comment: Instead of using valueUpdate, have you considered subscribing to the observable and firing off throttled updates from there? or are you already doing this?

Comment: I just edited the post to make the specifics more clear.

Comment: sorry, messed up the JS fiddle link, fixed now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `keyup` you can try using `input`:

```
valueUpdate: 'input'
```

**[KnockoutJS - The "value" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html):**

> "input" - updates your view model when the value of an <input> or <textarea> element changes. Note that this event is only raised by reasonably modern browsers (e.g., IE 9+).

Here's a sample JSFiddle ([**originally authored by Michael Best**](https://github.com/mbest)) that I found and adapted that illustrates it's usage, where it handles both key strokes and mouse clicks along with throttling:

### [Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wnxd5zjv/)

**HTML:**

```
<p>Type stuff here: 
    <input data-bind='value: instantaneousValue, valueUpdate: "input"' /></p>

<p>Current throttled value: <b data-bind='text: throttledValue'> </b></p>

<div data-bind="visible: loggedValues().length > 0">
    <h3>Stuff you have typed:</h3>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: loggedValues">
        <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
function AppViewModel() {
    this.instantaneousValue = ko.observable();
    this.throttledValue = ko.computed(this.instantaneousValue)
                            .extend({ throttle: 400 });

    // Keep a log of the throttled values
    this.loggedValues = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.throttledValue.subscribe(function (val) {
        if (val !== '')
            this.loggedValues.push(val);
    }, this);
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks! I somehow missed that that was an option for `valueUpdate`

Comment: Does this work when CLICKING the element, is it the same as jQuery.on()

Comment: wow, i don't know, wrote this code a long time ago. let me review.

Answer (score 3):

`textInput` is far better for 'save as you type'

You just need to replace `value:` with `textInput:`

It handles browser differences much better.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/textinput-binding.html

Comment: (you can still throttle it to avoid database saturation)